# C# check missing range from specified Range

Tags: c#

```
a = 1-30
b = 40-50
c = 60-100
```

The range above is 1-100. This range miss 31-39.

Does C# has a function that check whether specified range (1-100) missing any range (Ex:31-39) or missing value (Ex: 31)?

Regards

Comment: Your input is unclear. Are a,b and c are lists of integers?

Comment: Actually is a list of double

Answer (score 3):

Assuming 'input' contains the input, the following code will return true if any numbers are missing from the range:

```
bool result = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Except(input).Any();
```

Comment: Note that he will have to concatenate `a`,`b` and `c` to one `IEnumerable<int>` in order to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your own method like that:

```
    public List<int> CheckRange(int FirstRangeEnd, int SecondRangeStart)
    {
        List<int> missing = new List<int>();

        if (SecondRangeStart - FirstRangeEnd == 0)
        {
            missing.Add(-1);
            return missing;
        }
        for (int i= 0; i<= SecondRangeStart - FirstRangeEnd; i++)
        {
            missing.Add(FirstRangeEnd + i);
        }
        missing.RemoveAt(0);
        missing.RemoveAt(missing.Count - 1);
        return missing;
    }
```